# Redirect specific WordPress pages to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I have a WordPress site and want to redirect specific pages to HTTPS. Specifically, I want `http://www.mydomain.com/?page_id=4` to be redirected to `https://www.mydomain.com/?page_id=4`. The approach that I have taken is to add the following to .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.mydomain.com/?page_id=4 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/?page_id=4/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when I navigate to the page, it does not redirect. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're matching against `HTTP_HOST`. You should be matching against `REQUEST_URI`.

Answer (score 2):

Well ... `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable will be resolved to a domain name only and in your example it will be just `www.mydomain.com`. You'll need more than that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
# force secure version of this page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1?page_id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

1. You have to compare query string, protocol and optionally domain name separately via 3 RewriteCond statements.
2. I have removed `/$1` from target URL -- it makes no sense. All what this rule supposed to do is to redirect to secure version of this and only this one particular URL.
3. I'm not sure that this line is really required: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mydomain.com`. It should work fine without it.
4. Make sure that you put this rule in appropriate place -- it should be placed **BEFORE** WordPress rewrite rules.

---

**UPDATE:**
Alternative:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
# force secure version of this page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=(\d+)(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked and your explanation was very helpful. One follow-up question: I actually need to redirect all pages where page_id=3, 4 or 5.  (not just "www.mydomain.com/?page_id=4"). Do you know how I should edit the code to achieve this?

Comment: @brian Check my updated answer (2 small changes). It will work for the same URL but with different IDs. If you want to have it for completely different URL -- please provide an example or 2 so I can adjust the rule properly.

Comment: Hi. the updated code redirects the pages to https, but the pages are broken. Here's the error message I am getting: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [path]".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I figured out a workaround. I basically hardcode a block for each page#:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
#force secure version of page=4
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =page_id=4 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/?page_id=4 [R=301,L]

#force secure version of page=5
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =page_id=5 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/?page_id=5 [R=301,L]

#force secure version of page=6
...
```

Not elegant, but it works.

One last issue. It is possible for the URLs to contain characters after the page_id. For instance: www.mydomain.com/?page_id=4&category=1. Does anyone know how to place a wildcard after the page_id=4? Thanks!